# How to close stdin/out in C#?

Tags: c#, process

I have a scenario as follows:

[image]

Where a launcher starts a new process, redirects IO, and waits for it finish:

```
                p = Launch("second");
                p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                p.WaitForExit();
```

Now, I want to launch an "async" operation, I mean, I don't want "Launcher" to wait for process to finish.

To do that, I did as follows:

[image]

But the problem is that while Process1 leaves, Launcher keeps waiting for Process2 due to the redirected stdin/out.

I think a possible solution would be to close stdin/out on Process1 before launching Process2, but it is not working (tried CloseHandle(GetStdHandle) but doesn't work).

Any hints?

I think on linux fclose(0), fclose(1), fclose(2) would do but...

Thanks!

Code I tried for a repro case:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace threadsubproc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int ini = Environment.TickCount;

            string name = "first";

            try
            {
                if (args.Length == 1)
                {
                    name = args[0];
                }

                Process p = null;

                switch (name)
                {
                    case "first":
                        p = Launch("second");
                        p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        p.WaitForExit();

                        return;
                    case "second":
                        Launch("third");
                        return;
                    case "third":
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
                        return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(name, e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                File.AppendAllText(name, string.Format(
                    "{0} - {1} finished. {2} ms", DateTime.Now, name, Environment.TickCount - ini));
            }
        }

        static Process Launch(string arg)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "threadsubproc";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;

            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            p.Start();

            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use ReadToEnd() nor WaitForExit().  The latter is easily fixed with the Exited event.  The former requires BeginOutputReadLine().  With code that can see that you now get output from the second process.  What to do then is not so obvious, try calling Process.Dispose().  But it might deadlock, then you have to use CancelOutputRead() and just ignore the process.

Comment: And why you are doing `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` if you don't actually need that output? I mean it now waits not for process to finish, but for output (and if you remove reading output - there will be no delay).

Comment: I need it in the real case under some circumstances.

Comment: It seems (at least on Windows), that launching the "process2" with p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; makes the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, creating the process with the flag `UseShellExecute = true` prevents, in the described scenario, the parent process to keep waiting for its *grandson*, as you indicated (specifically, waiting to read to the end of the StandardOutput StreamReader, which was a restriction in your situation).

However, if your program runs under Mono on GNU/Linux (I have not tested this on macOS, nor using .NET Core), changing the flag is not enough. You will have to manually close the `stdio` Streams **before** launching the new process, and you must do so using the `fclose` function. Luckily enough, you can use the `Mono.Posix.dll` library.

This **will** work:

```cs
using Mono.Unix.Native;

    // Your code...

        case "second":
            DettachFromStdIO();
            Launch("third");
            return;

    // More of your code...

    static void DettachFromStdIO()
    {
        Stdlib.fclose(Stdlib.stdin);
        Stdlib.fclose(Stdlib.stdout);
        Stdlib.fclose(Stdlib.stderr);
    }

    // More of your code...
}
```

*Funnilly enough*, this **won't** work:

```cs
static void DettachFromStdIO()
{
    Console.In.Close();
    Console.Out.Close();
    Console.Error.Close();
}
```

And, of course, this won't either:

```cs
static void DettachFromStdIO()
{
    Console.OpenStandardInput().Close();
    Console.OpenStandardOutput().Close();
    Console.OpenStandardError().Close();
}
```

I have not found a way to get rid of the `Mono.Posix.dll` library, as the `fclose` function is defined in `stdio.h`, and you can't direcly invoke that through `pinvoke`.

Here is the code of the Stdlib class of the Mono runtime anyway https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/9a08e45324715e8b53dab5e4853c9ce79db6cb57/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix.Native/Stdlib.cs